# How can I pre-populate my billing/shipping information within Commerce?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce

When a user registers on my site, I am asking for their first, last, email and address.

I would like to be able to pass the data I already have along to commerce. So when I get to the `/address` screen, as much of that form is already pre-populated.

I see this:

```
{% set modelName = modelName is defined ? modelName : 'address' %}
{% set model = address is defined ? address : null %}
```

So I (think) the ideal solution is to set the model to the user model. I will never allow guest checkout on this site, yet I want to keep as much flexibility as possible (not delete a bunch of stuff). So I gave this a shot:

```
{% if currentUser %}
    {% set modelName = modelName is defined ? modelName : 'user' %}
    {% set model = user is defined ? user : null %}
{% else %}
    {% set modelName = modelName is defined ? modelName : 'address' %}
    {% set model = address is defined ? address : null %}
{% endif %}
```

And I get this error:

```
Craft\UserModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "businessName".
```

Which makes perfect sense - that's not in the user model.

I could go into the form filed and just set the values like this:

```
<input type="text" id="{{ modelName }}-firstName" class="form-control"
                   name="{{ modelName }}[firstName]"
                   value="{{ currentUser.firstName }}">
```

But is that going to lead to disaster? Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I gathered from the documentation, you could try this:

```
{% set customer = craft.commerce.getCustomer() %}
```

then

```
{{ customer.address.businessName }}
```

or it might be

```
{{ customer.addresses.businessName }}
```

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/customer-model